# Laravel BelongsToMany returning nested items

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, collections

I have a `BelongsToMany` relationship called `specifications`:

```php
public function specifications()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(
        Specification::class,
        'specification_product_link',
        'product_id',
        'specification_id'
    );
}
```

When I call this, I'd expect a collection of Specification items - one for each related item.

What I'm getting is a collection containing another collection - this sub-collection contains the related items.

[image: Output of dd]

While I can work with this, it's not what I expected and now I'm beginning to wonder whether I'm going mad or if this has always been the expected behaviour.

Shouldn't `BelongsToMany` return a collection with depth of 1?

Comment: please also bring your elequent query you have used to achieve this result .

Comment: I don't see the problem, you have an array of results

Comment: @MisterDebug he has a collection of 1 item, that one item is another collection and that collection holds all the data. It should be a collection of models, not a collection of a collection of models

Comment: Author, instead of gettin the values use `->toSql()`

Comment: @matiaslauriti upsi my bad